# Saving Android FaceDetector.Face[] on rotation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save the `FaceDetector.Face` array so that on a screen rotation, the facial detection does not have to be performed again. The app seems to take longer than a normal rotation. However, I can't store the faces array in `onSavedInstanceState` since it isn't serializable. I tried extending `FaceDetector.Face` with implementing serializable, but it doesn't have a default constructor. What should I do to save an `Object` array like this one on rotation, that I didn't implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a static Fragment without UI on that activity.
Once you do that, you can use it to store this data.
Keep in mind that FaceDetector.Face, is just an object that holds locations on bitmap and not the bitmap itself.